# Edge bevels weird behavior

Tags: bevel

I'm trying to make a simple rounded edge for a wall corner. But when a try to make a bevel, I have this result :

[image]

I don't understand why, the mesh is pretty simple and symmetric but the bevel is completely off...

Comment: have you tried to apply the scale in Object mode?

Comment: Oww, nope I completely forgot the deformation ! Thank you, it work after applying the scale :)